# Trouble getting the MvcMiniProfiler to work with EF4.1 and our Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

We're having lots of problems trying to get the MvcMiniProfiler to work with our EF implementation of the Repository Pattern.

Error:

> The entity type CustomEntityPewPewFooFoo is not part of the model for
> the current context.

Ok. this is the code we've done.

#### Custom UnitOfWork Context class

```
public class UnitOfWork : DbContext
{
    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString) 
        : base(GetProfiledConnection(connectionString))
    { }

    private static DbConnection GetProfiledConnection(string connectionString)
    {
        var parsedConnectionString = new
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        var connection = new
            SqlConnection(parsedConnectionString.ProviderConnectionString);
        return ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection);
    }

    public void Commit() { ... }
}
```

#### Add the factory settings stuff...

```
// NOTE: If this is not added, I get an error:
//      Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.
//      It may not be installed.
// In web.config ...
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
      <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

#### And finally, add this extra stuff....

```
// global.asax, in Application_Start().. because I'm caching
// some database data on startup.

var factory = new SqlConnectionFactory(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString);
var profiled = new MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbConnectionFactory(factory);
Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = profiled;

LoadApplicationDataToBeCachedForAllRequests(); // Go and hit the Db! Go Forth!!!
```

#### My connection string...

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="XWing_SqlServer_EF" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SqlServer.XWingModel.csdl|             
         res://*/SqlServer.XWingModel.ssdl|             
         res://*/SqlServer.XWingModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;              
         provider connection string='Data Source=Tarantino;Initial Catalog=XWing;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;'" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

#### And finally (again), then edmx info ..

```
- Entity Container Name: XWingEntities
- Namespace: XWing.Repositories.SqlServer
- Filename: XWingModel.edmx
```

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be that you have the same kind of problem I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342182). Basically, if the UnitOfWork class is not in the same assembly as the edmx, it will not work.

Comment: hmm... my edmx is in the same assembly as my *concrete* UoW class. But my concrete UoW does inherit from an *abstract* UoW which is from another assembly .... hmm...