# How to programatically read an EDMX file, using the MetadataWorkspace?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to programatically read an Entity Framework `EDMX` file.

I know it's a regular `XML` so I could just read the XML and extract the data on my own, but as there's an available `API`, I'm trying to use it.

The following code works, except that I cannot get the `OCSpace`, which represents the association between the Types and the Tables (this is the most important part for me)

```
var csdlEntities = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                      .Where(x => x is EntityType)
                      .ToList();

var csdlAssociations = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                          .Where(x => x is AssociationType)
                          .ToList();

var ssdlEntities = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                      .Where(x => x is EntityType)
                      .ToList();

var ssdlAssociations = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.SSpace)
                          .Where(x => x is AssociationType)
                          .ToList();

// EXCEPTION HERE
var mappings = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.OCSpace).Where(x => x is EntityType).ToList();
```

This is the line that throws an exception (InvalidOperationException, OCSpace has no associated collection):

```
var mappings = mdw.GetItems(DataSpace.OCSpace).Where(x => x is EntityType).ToList();
```

What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: Are the classes you want to reference and the workspace in the same namespace? Is the workspace at the right location? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342182/mvc-mini-profiler-entity-framework-gives-the-space-sspace-has-no-associated

Comment: It seems so, @derape. Thank you anyway.